# Why is my form's template variable showing an error?

Tags: angular

In the following form, I declare a template variable for the input element as follows:

```
#firstName=ngModel
```

Form:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-100">
  <form #loginForm="ngForm">
    <div class="container">
      <label *ngIf="user.loginType === 'register'" for="firstName"
        ><b>First Name</b></label
      >
      <input
        class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="user.firstName"
        *ngIf="user.loginType === 'register'"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter first name"
        name="firstName"
        #firstName="ngModel"
        required
     />
      <div *ngIf="firstName.errors?.['required']" class="error-color">
        FirstName is required
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I then check if the template variable has an error as shown here:

```
<div *ngIf="firstName.errors?.['required']" class="error-color">
  FirstName is required
</div>
```

Angular is giving me an error that: Property 'firstName' [in firstName.errors] does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'.ngtsc(2339)

As far as I know, the template variable does not have to be declared in the component.

Answer (score 1):

**firstName.errors?.['required']** it is incorrect syntax
either you do `firstName.errors['required']` or `firstName.errors?.required`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using template variable with structural directive `*ngIf` which creates its own scope, so template variable cannot be accessed outside of it, hence the error:

```
<input
   *ngIf="user.loginType === 'register'"

    #firstName="ngModel"
```

`firstName` is not accessible...

```
 <div *ngIf="firstName.errors?.['required']" class="error-color">
    FirstName is required
  </div>
```

See the docs:

> Template variable scope
>
> Just like variables in JavaScript or
> TypeScript code, template variables are scoped to the template that
> declares them.
>
> Similarly, Structural directives such as *ngIf and *ngFor, or
>  declarations create a new nested template scope, much
> like JavaScript's control flow statements like if and for create new
> lexical scopes. You cannot access template variables within one of
> these structural directives from outside of its boundaries.

> https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope

So, try reorganizing the code, maybe by moving `*ngIf="user.loginType === 'register'"` to the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

If the form you provided is the template of the login component, of course angular will ask for the variable firstName if it is declared or not in the that login component. So it depend how you instantiated your **ngForm** form instance:

for example if you injected a form builder to your login component, you can do something like this:

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    ngForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['']
    });
  }
}
```

then the template of your login component should look like this by adding formControlName directive:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center w-100">
  <form #loginForm="ngForm">
    <div class="container">
      <label *ngIf="user.loginType === 'register'" for="firstName"
        ><b>First Name</b></label
      >
      <input
        class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="user.firstName"
        *ngIf="user.loginType === 'register'"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter first name"
        name="firstName"
        formControlName="firstName"
        required
     />
      <div *ngIf="ngForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')" class="error-color">
        FirstName is required
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```